# How to concatenate php variables inside javascript console.log?

Tags: javascript, php

let's say `$urg = 'hora'`

folder in path `ga/hora/` has `54` files inside

I want this in console:

`fo hora 54`

inside a php file I have a `<script></script>` block and here is my try:

```
<script>
    console.log('fo ' + <?php echo $urg . ' ' . count(glob("ga/" . $urg . "/*")); ?>);
</script>
```

result:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

viewing the page source I have this:
`console.log('fo ' + hora 54);`

Please help

Comment: The output you want is `console.log('fo hora 54');`. Can you find the solution yourself now?

Comment: Why not using the JS template syntax? Stop using crappy concatenation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Solved - `console.log('fo ' + '<?php echo $urg; ?>' + ' ' + <?php echo count(glob("ga/" . $urg . "/*")); ?>);`. Thanks a lot